# how to prevent reloading a sidebar that containing router outlet in angular 2?

Tags: angular, components, router-outlet, sidenav

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    // console.log(this.translate.getLangs())
    const elemSidebar = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.app-inner > .sidebar-panel');
    const elemContent = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.app-inner > .mat-sidenav-content');

    if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 960px)`).matches && !this.isMac() && !this.compactSidebar) {
      Ps.initialize(elemSidebar, {wheelSpeed: 2, suppressScrollX: false});
      Ps.initialize(elemContent, {wheelSpeed: 2, suppressScrollX: false});
    }

    this.url = this.router.url;

    this._router = this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      document.querySelector('.app-inner .mat-sidenav-content').scrollTop = 0;
      this.url = event.url;
      this.runOnRouteChange();
    });
    this.getMenus();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.root.dir = 'rtl';
    this.runOnRouteChange();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._router.unsubscribe();
  }

  runOnRouteChange(): void {
    if (this.isOver()) {
      this.sidemenu.close();
    }
  }

  isOver(): boolean {
    if (this.url === '/apps/messages' ||
      this.url === '/apps/calendar' ||
      this.url === '/apps/media' ||
      this.url === '/maps/leaflet' ||
      this.url === '/taskboard') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 960px)`).matches;
    }
  }

  isMac(): boolean {
    let bool = false;
    if (navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') >= 0 || navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('IPAD') >= 0) {
      bool = true;
    }
    return bool;
  }

  menuMouseOver(): void {
    if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 960px)`).matches && this.collapseSidebar) {
      this.sidemenu.mode = 'over';
    }
  }

  menuMouseOut(): void {
    if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 960px)`).matches && this.collapseSidebar) {
      this.sidemenu.mode = 'side';
    }
  }


  getMenus() {
    let aclArray = [];
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(data => {
      if (!data.success) {
        this.snackBar.open(data.message, '', {
          duration: 2000,
          extraClasses: ['error-snackbar']
        });
      } else {
        let index = 0;
        console.log(data.user.rows)
        data.user.rows.forEach((row) => {
          // const roleid = row.rolesid;
          this.roleService.getRoleByID(row.roles_id).subscribe(role => {
            if (!role.success) {
              this.snackBar.open(role.message, '', {
                duration: 2000,
                extraClasses: ['error-snackbar'],
              });
            } else {
              console.log(role)
              role.role.rows.forEach(row => {
                this.roleService.getRoleAcls(row.id).subscribe(acls => {
                  if(!acls.success){
                    this.snackBar.open(role.message, '', {
                      duration: 2000,
                      extraClasses: ['error-snackbar'],
                    });
                  } else {
                    console.log(acls)
                    acls.acl.rows.forEach(row => {
                      const aclid = row.acl_id;
                      if(aclArray.indexOf(aclid) < 0) {
                        aclArray.push(aclid);
                      }
                    });
                    index ++;
                    if(index == data.user.rows.length){
                      aclArray.forEach(id => {
                        this.aclService.getAclById(id).subscribe(acl => {
                          console.log(acl.acl.rows)
                          acl.acl.rows.forEach(row => {
                            if(!isUndefined(row)){
                              const id = row.id;
                              this.aclService.getChildrenAcl(id).subscribe(children => {
                                if(!children.success){
                                  this.snackBar.open(children.message, '', {
                                    duration: 2000,
                                    extraClasses: ['error-snackbar']
                                  });
                                } else {
                                  for(let i in acl.acl.rows){
                                    acl.acl.rows[i]['children'] = [];
                                    children.children.rows.forEach(row1 => {
                                      if(aclArray.indexOf(row1.id) >= 0){
                                        acl.acl.rows[i]['children'].push(row1);
                                      }
                                    })
                                  }
                                }
                              });
                              for(let j in acl.acl.rows){
                                this.aclItems.push(acl.acl.rows[j]);
                              }
                            }
                          })
                        })
                      })
                    }
                  }
                })
              })
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<md-sidenav-container class="app-inner">
    <md-sidenav #sidemenu class="sidebar-panel" id="sidebar-panel" [mode]="isOver() ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!isOver()" (mouseover)="menuMouseOver()" (mouseout)="menuMouseOut()">
      <md-nav-list appAccordion class="navigation" >
        <!--(click)="updatePS()"-->
        <md-list-item appAccordionLink *ngFor="let menuitem of aclItems" group="{{menuitem.state}}">
          <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" [routerLink]="['/', menuitem.state]" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'">
            <md-icon>{{ menuitem.icon }}</md-icon>
            <span class="font">{{ menuitem.name | translate }}</span>
            <span fxFlex></span>
            <span class="menu-badge mat-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span>
          </a>
          <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" [routerLink]="['/mail', menuitem.state]" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'mail'">
            <md-icon>{{ menuitem.icon }}</md-icon>
            <span class="font">{{ menuitem.name | translate }}</span>
            <span fxFlex></span>
            <span class="menu-badge mat-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span>
          </a>
          <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" href="{{menuitem.state}}" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'extLink'">
            <md-icon>{{ menuitem.icon }}</md-icon>
            <span class="font">{{ menuitem.name | translate }}</span>
            <span fxFlex></span>
            <span class="menu-badge mat-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span>
          </a>
          <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" href="{{menuitem.state}}" target="_blank" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'extTabLink'">
            <md-icon>{{ menuitem.icon }}</md-icon>
            <span class="font">{{ menuitem.name | translate }}</span>
            <span fxFlex></span>
            <span class="menu-badge mat-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span>
          </a>
          <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" href="javascript:;" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'sub'">
            <md-icon>{{ menuitem.icon }}</md-icon>
            <span class="font">{{ menuitem.name | translate }}</span>
            <span fxFlex></span>
            <span class="menu-badge mat-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span>
            <md-icon class="menu-caret">arrow_drop_down</md-icon>
          </a>
          <md-nav-list class="sub-menu" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'sub'">
            <md-list-item *ngFor="let childitem of menuitem.children" routerLinkActive="open">
              <a [routerLink]="['/', menuitem.state, childitem.state ]" class="relative" >{{ childitem.name | translate }}</a>
            </md-list-item>
          </md-nav-list>
        </md-list-item>
        <!--<md-divider></md-divider>-->
        <!--<md-list-item>-->
          <!--<a (click)="addMenuItem()">-->
            <!--<md-icon>add</md-icon>-->
            <!--<span>Add</span>-->
          <!--</a>-->
        <!--</md-list-item>-->
      </md-nav-list>
    </md-sidenav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </md-sidenav-container>
```

I have an angular 2 app that contains a layout.component. in layout.component.html i have a sidemenu and within the side menu in router-outlet part, i run my other components. the code is like this:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
   <md-sidenav>(some codes here</md-sidenav>
   <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

in the side-nav i have some items to run the state of components. but when i click on one of them the side-nav is reloaded and sometimes it can't get the items.how can i reload only router-outlet and not the side nav?

and here is routing codes:

```
    {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      // {
      //   path: 'dashboard',
      //   loadChildren: './components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      // },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: './components/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'usermanagement',
        loadChildren: './components/usermanagement/usermanagement.module#UsermanagementModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren: './components/contact/contact.module#ContactModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'setting',
        loadChildren: './components/setting/setting.module#SettingModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'incoming',
        loadChildren: './components/mail/incoming/incoming.module#IncomingModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'outgoing',
        loadChildren: './components/mail/outgoing/outgoing.module#OutgoingModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'showincoming',
        loadChildren: './components/mail/showincoming/mail.module#MailModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'showoutgoing',
        loadChildren: './components/mail/showoutgoing/out.module#OutModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'viewoutgoing',
        loadChildren: './components/mail/view-outgoing/viewoutgoing.module#ViewoutgoingModule'
      },
      ]
  }];
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @vel i added a snippet the friest part is my layout-component.ts and the second part is the html, i'm using postgresql and i have a problem in running getMenues() when i click on a new state

Comment: and can you post the routing code?

Comment: @vel i edit it again

Comment: @ vel  and i get the net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when i click on the side-menu states

Comment: can you able to create plunkr with above the code?

Comment: well it's a little complicated i have to add to many codes!tnx for your help